# How do I dynamically update the JSON-LD Script for the Schema type = Product

Tags: json, product, schema.org, rating, json-ld

I have the following script, my question is given after the script.

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">
 {
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Coffee Mug",

  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "4.9",
    "ratingCount": "77"
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "AggregateOffer",
    "lowPrice": "5.76",
    "highPrice": "8",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "priceCurrency": "USD"
  }
}
```

I want to make sure that once the Star Rating is changed, it should also be changed in the script.

So can you please let me know how to do it?

**MY Question is:**

I am using a widget for star rating.
Right now there are 77 votes and aggregate rating is 4.9 out of 5.

Suppose I get 3 more votes and aggregate rating becomes 4.8 out of 5 for 80 votes.

So how can I change the script here dynamically?

Comment: This seems to be more a question about the system you are using to update the values, as opposed to the schema itself.

Comment: Yes. I don't want to update the schema. But I want to update the values dynamically.
As this is the static code, and Google discourage to show the Structured Data on SERP results, if we do not keep it updated with what is exactly available on the webpage. 

That is why I want to make it Dynamic.

I saw few websites are practicing it, but not able to find how they are able to make it.

Comment: Your question should be focussed around the 'widget' you are using, for which you have not disclosed any information to assist anyone in helping you. 

You should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello @ShannonYoung Thanks for replying. Finally, I've developed the script using scripting language, so it solved the dynamic update issue.